# Server monitoring software that will show each cpu seperatley

Tags: performance-monitoring, load-testing

We have been using New Relic to monitor our server load but it aggregates all of the CPUs into one measure. Is there a good tool that is similar but will show individual CPU load?

Answer (score 1):

There is `munin`. I found this page http://www.matija.si/system-administration/2014/04/01/a-munin-plugin-to-monitor-each-cpu-core-separately/ talking about a plugin that does just what you want.

Also, I know this isn't like new relic, but I'm wondering if `atop` will help you.

It shows individual cores/cpus. It also shows when things are maxed out and turns the line red to catch your attention.  It shows all sorts of useful information about cpu, memory, swap, disk io, network io, etc...

The only drawback is that it's not a web based, metric gathering daemon.

```
CPU | sys      14% | user      2% | irq       0% |               |              | idle    769% | wait     15% |              | steal     0% |               | guest     0% | avgf 1.48GHz | avgscal  36% |
cpu | sys       2% | user      0% | irq       0% |               |              | idle     95% | cpu004 w  3% |              | steal     0% |               | guest     0% | avgf 1.48GHz | avgscal  37% |
cpu | sys       2% | user      0% | irq       0% |               |              | idle     95% | cpu000 w  3% |              | steal     0% |               | guest     0% | avgf 1.48GHz | avgscal  36% |
cpu | sys       2% | user      0% | irq       0% |               |              | idle     95% | cpu006 w  2% |              | steal     0% |               | guest     0% | avgf 1.48GHz | avgscal  36% |
cpu | sys       2% | user      0% | irq       0% |               |              | idle     95% | cpu002 w  2% |              | steal     0% |               | guest     0% | avgf 1.47GHz | avgscal  36% |
cpu | sys       1% | user      0% | irq       0% |               |              | idle     97% | cpu001 w  1% |              | steal     0% |               | guest     0% | avgf 1.50GHz | avgscal  37% |
cpu | sys       1% | user      0% | irq       0% |               |              | idle     97% | cpu003 w  1% |              | steal     0% |               | guest     0% | avgf 1.49GHz | avgscal  37% |
cpu | sys       1% | user      0% | irq       0% |               |              | idle     97% | cpu005 w  1% |              | steal     0% |               | guest     0% | avgf 1.47GHz | avgscal  36% |
cpu | sys       1% | user      0% | irq       0% |               |              | idle     97% | cpu007 w  1% |              | steal     0% |               | guest     0% | avgf 1.47GHz | avgscal  36% |
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I would prefer a web based solution but this would certainly do the job.

Comment: @user16390 What about munin?